# Why is Switch Statement skipped?

Tags: c++

I want to learn why the switch statement is skipped in my code?
The Compiler just not read the data in the switch statement and returning 0.
I must be doing something wrong but can't point the mistake if it is a reason!

> Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mainMenu();
void ResultUsr(int);

int main()
{
    int userChoice;
    int ResultUsrInput;

    mainMenu();

    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> userChoice;

    ResultUsr(ResultUsrInput);
    return 0;
}
void mainMenu()
{
    cout << "Enter your Choice for calculation" << '\n';
    cout << "1 for Addition" << '\n';
    cout << "2 for Subtraction" << '\n';
}
void ResultUsr (int ResultUsrInput)
{
    int value1, value2;
    switch (ResultUsrInput)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter Your first Value: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter Your Second Value: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << "The result for the Entered values [" << value1 << "] and [" << value2 << "] is equal to [" << value1 + value2 << "]" << '\n';
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter Your first Value: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter Your Second Value: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << "The result for the Entered values [" << value1 << "] and [" << value2 << "] is equal to [" << value1 - value2 << "]" << '\n';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the function using the value you read from the user (`ResultUsr(userChoice)`)

Comment: It looks like you're confusing yourself by having two variables with the same purpose.

Comment: @molbdnilo I do it for testing purpose, and it should not skip the switch statement in any case.

Comment: @Tahir "_and it should not skip the switch statement in any case_" What? You didn't read anything to `ResultUsrInput` variable. And since you didn't initialize it either, it contains indeterminate value - reading from which invokes undefined behavior. One possible manifestation of it is the behavior, that you observe.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Yes I know it but why it skip the Switch function it must read it and ask me for user input.

Comment: ...it skips the switch because you don't assign any value to `ResultUsrInput`. Why would you expect that it would have value 1 or 2?

Comment: @Tahir Add `cout << ResultUsrInput` to the `ResultUsr` function and you will see that it has neither of the values you're interested in.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ResultUsr is Initialized in the main function and it takes an int variable in the global function as a reference to use in switch statement, I think this is not the reason for skipping.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I expect it because the switch statement is assigned to read 2 cases 1 and 2.

Comment: Ok, looks like the problem is that you just don't understand how switch works. If you have `switch (ResultUsrInput)` and cases 1 and 2, then it will execute case 1 if and only if the value of `ResultUsrInput` is 1. It will execute case 2 if and only if the value of `ResultUsrInput` is 2. If the value of `ResultUsrInput` is anything other than 1 or 2, it does nothing. And because you don't assign any value to  `ResultUsrInput` then it very likely won't have either of those values.

Comment: @Tahir "_ResultUsr is Initialized in the main function and it takes an int variable in the global function as a reference to use in switch statement, I think this is not the reason for skipping._" What? 1) `ResultUsr` is a function, and not a variable, so "it is initialized" doesn't make sense. 2) `userChoice` is assigned a value, via `cin`. `ResultUsrInput`, that you pass to `ResultUsr`, is not initialized, nor has a value assigned to it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's mean on this way iit will not work on which I am trying to make it work.

Comment: `switch` is **not** a function

Comment: @phuclv It's mean it is a statement.

Comment: @Tahir `ResultUsr(ResultUsrInput);` in `main()`should be `ResultUsr(userChoice);`, that's it. VTC as typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the main Function you must send and bind the user input by using the variable which you are already using to take user input.
EX: In the main Function You are taking user input by variable userChoice and Binding ResultUsrInput in the switch statement which is empty and return 0 or default case.

Bind userChoice or take input by ResultUsrInput.

> Check the Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void mainMenu();
double ResultUsr(int);

int main()
{
    //int userChoice;
    int ResultUsrInput;

    mainMenu();

    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> ResultUsrInput;

    ResultUsr(ResultUsrInput);
    return 0;
}
void mainMenu()
{
    cout << "Enter your Choice for calculation" << '\n';
    cout << "1 for Addition" << '\n';
    cout << "2 for Subtraction" << '\n';
}
double ResultUsr (int ResultUsrInput)
{
    int value1, value2;
    switch (ResultUsrInput)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter Your first Value: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter Your Second Value: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << "The result for the Entered values [" << value1 << "] and [" << value2 << "] is equal to [" << value1 + value2 << "]" << '\n';
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter Your first Value: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter Your Second Value: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << "The result for the Entered values [" << value1 << "] and [" << value2 << "] is equal to [" << value1 - value2 << "]" << '\n';
        break;
        default:
        cout<<"Invalid Input or error in Code";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, btw why you have limits included?

Comment: @Tahir its my Habit and also it is a useful lib to control user input restrictions to protect programs from crashes and invalid behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You have not assigned value to variable `ResultUsrInput` when calling function `ResultUsr(ResultUsrInput)`. You have to assign the value first. It seems in your code you want to get choice from user so you should use `userChoice` in parameter when calling `ResultUsr` in `main()` function

```
ResultUsr(userChoice);
```

The better approach is you should have `default` case as shown in code below.

```
void ResultUsr (int ResultUsrInput)
{
    int value1, value2;
    switch (ResultUsrInput)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter Your first Value: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter Your Second Value: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << "The result for the Entered values [" << value1 << "] and [" << value2 << "] is equal to [" << value1 + value2 << "]" << '\n';
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter Your first Value: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter Your Second Value: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << "The result for the Entered values [" << value1 << "] and [" << value2 << "] is equal to [" << value1 - value2 << "]" << '\n';
        break;
    default:
        court<<"Default case executed";
        break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ResultUsrInput variable is used without initialization.